# SharePoint Framework (SPFX) onInit() Promises

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

I'm in the process of getting my feet wet with SPFx Application Customizers and have a question regarding the use of promises in TS.

Before my onRender() method is called inside of onInit(), I need to call two functions using PnP JS:

- The first retrieves the web title
- The second fetches some user-profile metadata

How can I ensure these two functions complete before the onRender() logic is executed?

```
    public onInit(): Promise<void> {
        Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `Initialized ${strings.Title}`);

        pnp.sp.web.select("Title").get().then(w => {
          this._webTitle = w.Title;
        });

        pnp.sp.profiles.myProperties.get().then(function (result) {
          var userProperties = result.UserProfileProperties;
          console.log(userProperties);
          userProperties.forEach(function (property) {
            if (property.Key == "PreferredName") {
              this._userDisplayName = property.Value;
              console.log('user display name: ' + this._userDisplayName);
            }
          });
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log("Error: " + error);
        });
    return Promise.resolve<void>();
  }
```

Currently, I have a race-condition issue where my application customizer is rendered before getting a response in my onInit() functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Batching](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Batching) the 2 requests as suggested by [Venkat Konjeti](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/65426/venkat-konjeti) is a great idea, but the question of how to delay your render until these are finished is demonstrated in the [jquery-application-toastr sample](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/jquery-application-toastr) (full disclosure, this is my sample).

Specifically in the [SpfxToastrApplicationCustomizer.ts file](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/blob/master/samples/jquery-application-toastr/src/extensions/spfxToastr/SpfxToastrApplicationCustomizer.ts). In the webpart class there is a private promise property. This is set in the `onInit` function when the call to go retrieve the data is made. However, there is no handler (`then`) at the time.

Later, in the `onRender` method once things are ready, the then is finally applied and handled. This solves the race condition. Promises will allow you to apply the `then` function before or after they are resolved. If they haven't resolved then your `then` won't be called until it is, if the promise already completed, your `then` will simply receive the results when you're ready for them.

Here's an example (borrowing the batch function from Venkat Konjeti's answer):

```
private myPromise: Promise<any>;

public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.myPromise = this.getData()
}

public onRender(): void {
    this.myPromise.then((results: any) => {
        //Do some rendering stuff
    });
}

function getData() {
    let batch = $pnp.sp.createBatch();

    $pnp.sp.web.select("Title").inBatch(batch).get().then(w => {
        console.log(w.Title);
    });

    $pnp.sp.profiles.myProperties.inBatch(batch).get().then(result => {
        var userProperties = result.UserProfileProperties;
        console.log(userProperties);
        userProperties.forEach(function (property) {
            if (property.Key == "PreferredName") {
              this._userDisplayName = property.Value;
              console.log('user display name: ' + this._userDisplayName);
            }
        });
    });

    return batch.execute();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help @theChristKent! After a few minor tweaks to the above code, I've got this working! Just a word of caution – sp-pnp-js has a bug in older versions that causes inner promises to not be resolved on batch.execute. This gave me some grief initially once transitioning to a CDN: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/issues/417

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the batch function. Here is example JavaScript code converted to the pnp batch executions.

```
function rednderBody() {

    var promise = getMyWebDetails();
    promise.then(() => console.log("All done!"));

}

function getMyWebDetails() {
    var batch = $pnp.sp.createBatch();

    $pnp.sp.web.select("Title").inBatch(batch).get().then(w => {
        console.log(w.Title);
    });

    $pnp.sp.profiles.myProperties.inBatch(batch).get().then(result => {
        var userProperties = result.UserProfileProperties;
        console.log(userProperties);
        userProperties.forEach(function (property) {
            if (property.Key == "PreferredName") {
              this._userDisplayName = property.Value;
              console.log('user display name: ' + this._userDisplayName);
            }
        });
    });

    return batch.execute();
}

rednderBody();
```

Comment: this batches the two PNP calls together, but how do I integrate this with the promise associated with onInit()? These calls would execute as a batch, but still complete after the SharePoint Framework's onRender() function is called.

Comment: Can you try this `promise.then(() => {return Promise.resolve<void>();}); `. I haven`t tried this but give a try.

Comment: This errors – "[ts] A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value."